# Sql query has low performance on SQL server management studio

Tags: sql, sql-server

I hope this year will be great.
I am new to SQL server and i'm trying to display some values with the lower cost. At now, the query gives me the results in almost 17 seconds. I would like to have performance almost 8 to 5 seconds.
This is a query to display data on a graph. I take this query and I insert it into a php file.
I have created indexes so I have succeed from 25 seconds to 17 seconds. I don't know what to do next.
Here is my code:

```
DECLARE @jahre TABLE(jahr int);
WITH CTE AS
(
       SELECT 2013 AS JournalDatum
       UNION ALL
       SELECT JournalDatum+1
       FROM CTE
       WHERE JournalDatum < YEAR(GETDATE())
)
INSERT INTO @jahre SELECT * FROM CTE


DECLARE @years4Pivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),@query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @years4Pivot = STUFF((SELECT ',' + '['+CAST(jahr AS VARCHAR(4))+ ']' FROM @jahre FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')


    SET @query = N'



    WITH cashin AS  (

        SELECT * FROM (

            SELECT

                /* 
                dbo.cdGetFDOM(JournalDatum) myDatum
                ,MONTH(JournalDatum) AS Monat
                ,jou.KreisLFN
                */

                DATENAME(YEAR, JournalDatum) AS Jahr
                ,jou.ObjektLFN
                ,CAST(SUM(FibuHabenNetto) as float)-CAST(SUM(FibuSollNetto) as float)-CAST(SUM(FibuMWST) as float) fibuBetrag
                ,(''NKM_'' + REPLACE(SUBSTRING(EinheitArtBezeichnung,2,2),'')'','''')) EinhArtPos
                ,mieteig.MietEigLFN
                ,mieteig.MietEigCode1
            FROM
                dbo.TF0700_Journal AS jou
                JOIN dbo.TF0720_Fibu AS fibu ON fibu.JournalLFN = jou.JournalLFN 
                JOIN dbo.TF0710_JournalOPPos AS joupos ON joupos.OpPosLFN = fibu.OPPosLFN 
                JOIN dbo.TA0270_Position AS pos ON pos.PositionLFN = joupos.PositionLFN
                JOIN dbo.TA0310_MietEigEinheit ME ON ME.EinheitLFN = joupos.EinheitLFN
                JOIN dbo.TZ0310_EinheitArt EA ON ME.EinheitArtLFN = EA.EinheitArtLFN
                JOIN dbo.TA0300_MietEig mieteig ON joupos.MietEigLFN = mieteig.MietEigLFN
            WHERE
                JournalArt = 21 
                AND pos.PositionArt=1

                
                AND RIGHT(LEFT(MietEigCode1,5),1) NOT IN 
                                                    (
                                                    SELECT MietEigCode1 from TA0300_MietEig 
                                                    WHERE RIGHT(LEFT(MietEigCode1,5),1) IS NOT NULL 
                                                    AND RIGHT(LEFT(MietEigCode1,5),1) NOT LIKE '' ''
                                                    )
                

            GROUP BY

                /* 
                dbo.cdGetFDOM(JournalDatum) myDatum
                ,MONTH(JournalDatum) AS Monat
                ,jou.KreisLFN
                */

                DATENAME(YEAR, JournalDatum)
                ,jou.ObjektLFN
                ,REPLACE(SUBSTRING(EinheitArtBezeichnung,2,2),'')'','''')
                ,mieteig.MietEigLFN
                ,mieteig.MietEigCode1


                
        ) AS Q 
        PIVOT (SUM(fibuBetrag) FOR EinhArtPos IN (NKM_W,NKM_G,NKM_B,NKM_GA,NKM_SP,NKM_S)) P
    )


 SELECT *

    FROM 

    (
        SELECT

            /*
            --c.myDatum
            --,c.Monat
            --,c.KreisLFN
            */

            c.Jahr as Jahr
            ,c.ObjektLFN
            ,ISNULL(NKM_W,0)+ISNULL(NKM_G,0)+ISNULL(NKM_B,0)+ISNULL(NKM_GA,0)+ISNULL(NKM_SP,0)+ISNULL(NKM_S,0) AS Nettokaltmiete
            ,obj.ObjektBezeichnung
        FROM cashin c
        LEFT JOIN dbo.TA0200_Objekt obj ON c.ObjektLFN=obj.ObjektLFN
        WHERE DOMUS4000_MIRROR_1.dbo.cdIsValidImDatum(GETDATE(),3,obj.ObjektLFN)>0

    ) tbl1

        PIVOT (
            SUM(Nettokaltmiete)
            FOR Jahr IN (' + @years4Pivot + N')
        ) pvt 


ORDER BY ObjektBezeichnung ASC '

    exec sp_executesql @query;
```

and the screenshots of execution plan:
[image]

[image]

Here is the link for a better looking :)

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HkSEjV7Av

Also the code for the function cdIsValidImDatum is here:

```
    USE [DOMUS4000_MIRROR_1]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ALTER   FUNCTION [dbo].[cdIsValidImDatum](@bDate DATE, @bLevel int,@lfn int) RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @tmpInt INT
    /*
    @bLevel
    1: Mandant
    2: Kreis
    3: Objekt
    4: Einheit
    */
    IF @bDate IS NULL OR @bLevel IS NULL OR @lfn IS NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @tmpInt = 0
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        IF @bLevel = 4
        BEGIN
            SET @tmpInt =
            (
                SELECT
                    COUNT(*)
                FROM
                    dbo.TA0310_MietEigEinheit AS einh LEFT JOIN
                    dbo.TA0200_Objekt AS obj ON einh.ObjektLFN = obj.ObjektLFN LEFT JOIN
                    dbo.TA0100_Kreis AS kre ON obj.KreisLFN = kre.KreisLFN LEFT JOIN
                    dbo.TA0010_Mandant AS man ON kre.MandantLFN = man.MandantLFN
                WHERE 
                    LEFT(ISNULL(man.MandantCode, ''), 1) <> '0'
                    AND
                    RIGHT(LEFT(ISNULL(man.MandantCode, ''), 3),1) <> '1'
                    AND
                    (man.MandantBeginn <= @bDate OR man.MandantBeginn IS NULL)
                    AND
                    (man.MandantEnde >= @bDate OR man.MandantEnde IS NULL)
                    AND
                    LEFT(ISNULL(kre.KreisCode, ''), 1) <> '0'
                    AND
                    RIGHT(LEFT(ISNULL(obj.ObjektCode, ''), 2),1) <> '0'
                    AND
                    (obj.ObjektVerwaltungsbeginn <= @bDate OR obj.ObjektVerwaltungsbeginn IS NULL)
                    AND 
                    (obj.ObjektVerwaltungsende >= @bDate OR obj.ObjektVerwaltungsende IS NULL)
                    AND
                    (einh.GueltigBis >= @bDate OR einh.GueltigBis IS NULL)
                    AND
                    (einh.EinheitErstbezug <= @bDate OR einh.EinheitErstbezug IS NULL)
                    AND einh.EinheitLFN=@lfn
            )
        END
        ELSE IF @bLevel = 3 
        BEGIN
            SET @tmpInt =
            (
                SELECT
                    COUNT(*)
                FROM
                    dbo.TA0200_Objekt AS obj LEFT JOIN
                    dbo.TA0100_Kreis AS kre ON obj.KreisLFN = kre.KreisLFN LEFT JOIN
                    dbo.TA0010_Mandant AS man ON kre.MandantLFN = man.MandantLFN
                WHERE 
                    LEFT(ISNULL(man.MandantCode, ''), 1) <> '0'
                    AND
                    RIGHT(LEFT(ISNULL(man.MandantCode, ''), 3),1) <> '1'
                    AND
                    (man.MandantBeginn <= @bDate OR man.MandantBeginn IS NULL)
                    AND
                    (man.MandantEnde >= @bDate OR man.MandantEnde IS NULL)
                    AND
                    LEFT(ISNULL(kre.KreisCode, ''), 1) <> '0'
                    AND
                    RIGHT(LEFT(ISNULL(obj.ObjektCode, ''), 2),1) <> '0'
                    AND
                    (obj.ObjektVerwaltungsbeginn <= @bDate OR obj.ObjektVerwaltungsbeginn IS NULL)
                    AND 
                    (obj.ObjektVerwaltungsende >= @bDate OR obj.ObjektVerwaltungsende IS NULL)
                    AND
                    obj.ObjektLFN=@lfn
            )
        END
        ELSE IF @bLevel = 2
        BEGIN
            SET @tmpInt =
            (
                SELECT
                    COUNT(*)
                FROM
                    dbo.TA0100_Kreis AS kre INNER JOIN
                    dbo.TA0010_Mandant AS man ON kre.MandantLFN = man.MandantLFN
                WHERE 
                    LEFT(ISNULL(man.MandantCode, ''), 1) <> '0'
                    AND
                    RIGHT(LEFT(ISNULL(man.MandantCode, ''), 3),1) <> '1'
                    AND
                    (man.MandantBeginn <= @bDate OR man.MandantBeginn IS NULL)
                    AND
                    (man.MandantEnde >= @bDate OR man.MandantEnde IS NULL)
                    AND
                    LEFT(ISNULL(kre.KreisCode, ''), 1) <> '0'
                    AND
                    kre.KreisLFN=@lfn
            )
        END
        ELSE IF @bLevel = 1
        BEGIN
            SET @tmpInt =
            (
                SELECT
                    COUNT(*)
                FROM
                    dbo.TA0010_Mandant AS man
                WHERE 
                    LEFT(ISNULL(man.MandantCode, ''), 1) <> '0'
                    AND
                    RIGHT(LEFT(ISNULL(man.MandantCode, ''), 3),1) <> '1'
                    AND
                    (man.MandantBeginn <= @bDate OR man.MandantBeginn IS NULL)
                    AND
                    (man.MandantEnde >= @bDate OR man.MandantEnde IS NULL)
                    AND
                    man.MandantLFN=@lfn
            )
        END
    END
    RETURN @tmpInt 
END
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227005/discussion-on-question-by-nick-zagkanas-sql-query-has-low-performance-on-sql-ser).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally guys I found the solution. I dropped it down to 4 seconds. I did

LEFT JOIN in this

```
LEFT JOIN dbo.TA0300_MietEig mieteig ON joupos.MietEigLFN = mieteig.MietEigLFN
```

and in the WHERE section I fielded with this:

```
WHERE
                JournalArt = 21 
                AND pos.PositionArt=1
                AND RIGHT(LEFT(mieteig.MietEigCode1,5),1) IS NOT NULL
                AND RIGHT(LEFT(MietEigCode1,5),1) LIKE '' ''
```

The results were the same.
If anyone has more accurate answer please do not hesitate to explain in this post.

Thanks again.

Comment: No need to `LEFT JOIN` if you are asking for the value to be `NOT NULL` you can switch to `INNER JOIN` and also remove the check for null because the `LIKE` won't return if it's null. Also you really need to normalize those fields, you shouldn't store multiple bits of data in one field. And this `RIGHT(LEFT(MietEigCode1,5),1)` can be changed to `MietEigCode1 LIKE '???? '